# Date provided for the Azure Data Factory pipeline should sink with the Azure Databricks Notebook query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

Whenever I am providing the date for the pipeline, it creates a new folder with the same date in ADLS. I can read the data by providing the hardcoded date, but when I again debug the pipeline it create new folder.

Problem - the date I have provided in the query is hardcoded, I need to make it flexible like whenever I debug the pipeline, the query automatically get the new folder.
[image]
[image]
Attaching the screenshot for the better understanding.enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below approach. You can create a new folder automatically by using dynamic content.

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results by using copy activity**:

1. *Open sink dataset in the copy activity .*
   [image]
2. *Go to parameter and  create **Parameter Name `folder`**.*
   [image]
3. *Go to connection , Add dynamic content `@dataset().folder` in the folder path .*

[image]

4. *when you created a parameter name, the same name will be displayed in dataset properties as shown below image.*

- *Add dynamic content inside Value:* `@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy/MM/DD'))`

[image]

***Now , you can check Pipeline successfully executed and got the output:***

[image]

Comment: The first part for the creation of parameter is correct, I have done this already. The issue is with the query like I have written the hardcoded query, I need this to be flexible. Whenever pipeline is creating the folder, the query automatically sink with that folder. Please check the 2nd image for the query.

Comment: `@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy/MM/DD'))` this query makes it flexible for ADF to write it to sink folder and it creates new folder for every day. And do you want flexible query in databricks?